# How to detect outliers within sampleID

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My `pandas.DataFrame` composed of many light spectrums that should be similar when within the SampleId. I want to detect the possible outliers by counting the points not within the +/- `3*np.std`. In the example below we can see the that the last line (with 100) is a outlier.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SID':[0  ,   0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2  ,],
                   'R1': [2.2, 1.9, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4  ,],
                   'R2': [3  , 3  , 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5  ,],
                   'R3': [3  , 3  , 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 100,]})
```

I'm looking for an elegant solution to subtract the mean depending the sampleID and verify the result is within a limit threshold:

```
df - df.groupby('SID').mean() > df.groupby('SID').std()*3 #That doesn't work !
```

I can make it work by using dictionaries and apply method, but I'm sure `pandas` has an existing solution.

Comment: so you want to eliminate all rows where where any of the `Rn`s are outside of 3 standard deviations?

Comment: It's the general idea yes (my plan was to count True's and define a limit), I have 292 `Rn`

Comment: `(df[['R1','R2','R3']]- df.groupby('SID').transform('mean').values) > df.groupby('SID').transform('std')*3`

Comment: @Wen OP has many `Rn` columns

Comment: @Wen, that's working great ! @modesitt, the `Rn` are named with a good logic and I can use a comprehension list to filter the dataset.

Comment: @LaurentR sounds good. I did provide a solution without any `groupby`s

Comment: @modesitt, the mean and std must be calculated with a `groupby` on the SampleId, not across the complete column.

Comment: oh i get you @LaurentR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get all the `Rn` columns.

```
helper_df = df.filter(regex=(r'R\d'))
```

then calculate the mean and std of each column

```
means = helper_df.mean(axis=0)
stds = helper_df.std(axis=0)
```

then all the outliers will be `True` here:

```
outliers = (df - means) > 3*stds
```

all rows that have outliers will:

```
outlier_samples = df[outliers.any(axis=1)]
```

(note that 100 is actually not an outlier in your above data because the `mean` of `R3` is 14 and the `std` is 32)